# powershell command to eject the device connected through usb does not work first time

Tags: powershell

I have a java application which interacts with a device connected through USB drive. I want to eject the device after processing. The below command works, but I have to try in a loop to make sure its ejected.

**powershell.exe ((New-Object -comObject Shell.Application).NameSpace(17).ParseName('E:\').InvokeVerb('Eject'))**

Not sure if any issue with the command. Sometimes it works after 3 or 4 times.

Can anyone help?

Added the screen shot here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWdWp.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot reproduce the error, but it seems, that the type of the drive object changes from "USB Drive" to "Removable drive", when invoking the Eject verb.

You might want to add a short script to your routine. Something like:

```bsh
$obj = (New-Object -comObject Shell.Application).namespace(17).ParseName('E:\')
$Type = $obj.Type
while ($Type-eq 'USB Drive'){
    $obj.InvokeVerb('Eject')
    $Type= $obj.Type
}
```

Then you don't have to run the code several times and wait for PowerShell to spin up.

Here it is as a one-liner:

```bsh
powershell.exe -Command {$obj = (New-Object -comObject Shell.Application).namespace(17).ParseName('E:\');$Type = $obj.Type;while ($Type-eq 'USB Drive'){Write-Host 'Removing drive';$obj.InvokeVerb('Eject');$Type= $obj.Type}}
```

If you want to run the command in cmd and not in PowerShell, you need to format it like this:

```
powershell.exe -Command $obj = (New-Object -comObject Shell.Application).namespace(17).ParseName('E:\');$Type = $obj.Type;while ($Type-eq 'USB Drive'){Write-Host 'Removing drive';$obj.InvokeVerb('Eject');$Type= $obj.Type}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I would need to execute the command from java program. Is it possible to run the above command as a single line?

Comment: I made the above script as single line, but still it does not eject after single use.

powershell.exe  ((New-Object -comObject Shell.Application).namespace(17).ParseName('E:') ^| Where-Object {$_.Type-eq 'USB Drive'}) ^| ForEach-Object { $_.InvokeVerb('Eject') }

Not sure, if I missed anything.

Comment: Updated the answer :-)

Comment: thanks for the script. Its not working at my end when I tried it. Its just printing the $obj.

c:\>powershell.exe -Command {$obj = (New-Object -comObject Shell.Application).namespace(17).ParseName('E:\');$Type = $obj.Type;while ($Type-eq 'USB Drive'){Write-Host 'Removing drive';$obj.InvokeVerb('Eject');$Type= $obj.Type}}

$obj = (New-Object -comObject Shell.Application).namespace(17).ParseName('E:\');$Type = $obj.Type;while ($Type-eq 'USB Drive'){Write-Host 'Removing drive';$obj.InvokeVerb('Eject');$Type= $obj.Type}

Comment: When I run the command, it detaches the USB drive. Can you upload a screenshot of your console with the command and result?

Comment: Added the screen shot in my original question.

Comment: Excellent, Thanks for your help. I am able to resolve it and now it ejects always.

Comment: Unbelievable! I had the same problem when running the command outside PowerShell.